# sql сокращение выборки

Tags: sql

Подскажите как сформировать SELECT, чтобы исключить отмеченные повторения на скриншоте в выборке
[image: скриншот выборки]

Comment: С точка зрения SQL отмеченное в принципе не является повторениями - во всяком случае, на множестве попавших на скриншот значений.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял это *PHP* и  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

По умолчанию там есть второй параметр `resulttype` - необязательный параметр принимает значение константы, которая указывает на тип массива, в который требуется поместить данные. Возможные значения параметра: `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM` или `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

По умолчанию `MYSQLI_BOTH` то есть и то и то. Надо поставить `MYSQLI_ASSOC`  либо использовать [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @АртёмСидоркин если помогло - можно галочку напротив ответа ткнуть)